# Donations (NPSP) duplicating to cloned contact records

Tags: opportunity, contact, clone, npsp

We are using the clone function to duplicate contacts. We noticed when we do this and then add a donation record to one of the contacts (the original contact we cloned from for example), the donation is also created in the cloned contact record.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click the "Clone" button on a contact record
2. Edit the new (cloned) contact record - Add a donation record to this contact
3. Save the contact and view it... the new donation record shows up
4. View the original contact (the one that was cloned)... the donation record added to the new contact also shows in the original contact

Is there a way to clone contacts without the opportunity data copying to each record every time it is added/updated? We simply want to use the clone option to create new contacts and those new contact records should be completely independent from the original contact record.

Thanks!
Craig

Comment: You're doing what's referred to as a "deep clone". There should be Options you can set on the clone button. Disable the keep Id and related records options (this is from memory, so actual options may be different).